# How to add more topic type in bbpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I've asked this question on bbpress support 3 days ago but they didn't reply yet also didn't find solution on google as well. I need this as soon as possible, please help.

I want to add more topic type in bbpress just like "Normal", "Sticky" and "Super Sticky". I want to add "Urgent" in the list too. For reference please see belwo image.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible through the front end.

Comment: @Adarsh I know its not possible through front end, there might be a hook or so but didn't find it yet.